# Can I create a single validation error bag for Lighthouse PHP, include GraphQL validation issues

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

Is there a way when using Lighthouse PHP to get the GraphQL validation error to appear side by side with the Laravel validation errors?  Currently the graph QL validations cause a different type of error, before the Laravel error are run.

For example if I submit the following mutation:

```
mutation register(
   password: 123456
) {
  id
}
```

I will get back just an error back

```
{ "message": "Variable username not present. Expected type String",
  "extensions": {
      "category": "graphql"
   }
}
```

Then when I submit:

```
mutation register(
   username: somethingStupid
   password: 123456
) {
  id
}
```

Then I will get this error:

```
{ "message": "Validation failed for the field [register].",
  "extensions": {
      "validation": {
           "username": [
                "Username must be unique."
                    ]
            },
            "password": [
                "Password must contain letters and numbers"
                    ]
            },
       "category": "validation"
    },
}
```

For my front end I'd like them only to have to expect a single error bag, but this seems to require them to expect two different types of errors. Assuming my Laravel validations cover the schema definition, I would like for them never to see the GraphQl errors. Or am I missing the concept of GraphQL somehow?